# What is -pa and -pz in erlang?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I was trying to modify `mod_log_chat` module in `ejabberd-contrib` where I saw the following command in `build.sh`

```bash
erl -pa ../ejabberd-dev/ebin -pz ebin -make
```

Can someone explain what is `-pa` and `-pz`? I am not getting a satisfactory information from web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html

> In interactive mode, the code server maintains a search path --
>   usually called the code path -- consisting of a list of directories,
>   which it searches sequentially when trying to load a module.

From: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

> `-pa Dir1 Dir2`
>
> Adds the specified directories to the beginning of the code path, similar to `code:add_pathsa/1`.
>
> `-pz Dir1 Dir2`
>
> Adds the specified directories to the end of the code path, similar to `code:add_pathsz/1`.